# Pushing a vector into an vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a 2d vector

```
typedef vector <double> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> data_t;
data_t data;
```

So my 2d vector is data here. It has elements like say,

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Now I want to insert these elements into another 2d vector

```
 std::vector< vector<double> > window;
```

So what I did was to create an iterator for traversing through the rows of data and pushing it into window like

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> >::iterator data_it;

    for (data_it = data.begin() ; data_it != data.end() ; ++data_it){
      window.push_back ( *data_it );
      // Do something else
      }
```

Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong or suggest a way to do this ? BTW I want to push it just element by element because I want to be able to do something else inside the loop too. i.e. I want to check for a condition and increment the value of the iterator inside. for example, if a condition satisfies then I'll do data_it+=3 or something like that inside the loop.

Thanks

P.S. I asked this question last night and didn't get any response and that's why I'm posting it again.

Comment: What's the problem at all? BTW, if you want to push the double values element by element, you need nested for loops.

Comment: What else do you want to do in the loop?  Chances are you do not need to copy the item element by element, but we need more information to give you a proper answer.  A simple nested for loop would suffice otherwise.

Comment: Please, could you be clear on your actual question? Your code looks good so far.

Comment: I want to check for a condition and increment the value of the iterator inside. for example, if a condition satisfies then I'll do data_it+=3 or something like that inside the loop.

Comment: "I asked this question last night and didn't get any response and that's why I'm posting it again." - Please update the original question instead of re-asking the same question. At least very least provide a [link to the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541556/pushing-an-array-into-a-vector).

Comment: I updated it a little bit. That's why I re-posted it.

Comment: You have to tell us what the problem us. Also, please don't just repost when your question doesn't get answered: consider improving the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is:

> to check for a condition and increment
>   the value of the iterator inside. for
>   example, if a condition satisfies then
>   I'll do it+=3 or something like that
>   inside the loop.

Then using a `while` loop instead of a `for`migth help:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> >::iterator data_it = data.begin();

while (data_it != data.end()) {
  window.push_back ( *data_it );
  if (SatisfiesCondition(*data_it)) {
    data_it += 3;
  }
  else {
    ++data_it;
  }
}
```

Comment: My actual question is  window.push_back ( *data_it ); is not working. What would be the alternative ? How can I insert elements into a vector like that ?

Comment: @Antonio: and what if the next-to-last element satisfies the condition ?

Comment: @Sunil: How do you know `window.push_back ( *data_it );`is not working? Is it a compiler error or a run time error?

Comment: @icecrime: that would be a problem :). You would have to check that before increment. The `+= 3`is just an example. And I obviiously misunderstood Sunil's question.

Comment: @Antonio: It is a runtime error. It always gives me segmentation fault.

Comment: @Antonio: It is a huge code but I'm having error only in this part. if I don't call this function then everything runs fine.

Comment: @Sunil: Segmentation fault occurs when accessing memory out of you program's scope. Using a debugger will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently copies the data row-by-row, not element-by-element.

For element-wise copying of a 2D array, you need a nested loop, as @AmbiguousX already mentioned.
If you start with an empty 2D array `window`, the code should look like this:

```
for (std::vector< record_t >::iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); i++)
{
  std::vector<double> row;
  for (std::vector<double>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++)
  {
    row.push_back(*j);
    // do something else with *j
  }
  window.push_back(row);
}
```

Comment: "Your code currently copies the data row-by-row, not element-by-element."

Nothing wrong with what he's doing. Copying each row will copy its elements too.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: In principle not, but the question was for doing an element-wise copy, so I thought to point it out.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I must have skimmed over that paragraph in the OP's question.