# Initialization of array on heap

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

How do i manually initiate values in array on heap?
If the array is local variable (in stack), it can be done very elegant and easy way, like this:

```
int myArray[3] = {1,2,3};
```

Unfortunately, following code

```
int * myArray = new int[3];
myArray = {1,2,3};
```

outputs an error by compiling

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
error: expected `;' before ‘{’ token
```

Do i have to use cycle, or not-so-much-elegant way like this?

```
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[2] = 3;
```

Comment: from the looks of your example, you want to fill array elements 0 .. N, with values 1 .. N + 1.   A for loop would do this nicely.   What is your actual intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting: [Pushing an array into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541556/pushing-an-array-into-a-vector/4541707#4541707)

However, if that doesn't do it for you try the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
...


const int length = 32;

int stack_array[length] = { 0 ,32, 54, ... }
int* array = new int[length];

std::copy(stack_array, stack_array + length, &array[0]);
```

Comment: You made a mistake, it should be `std::copy(stack_array, stack_array+5, &array[0]);`

Comment: VLA (variable length array)  is not a part of C++ standard

Comment: VLAs in C++ so -1

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished today with the following syntax:

```
int * myHeapArray = new int [3] {1, 2, 3};
```

Notice you have to match the size of the structure you're allocating with the size of the initializer-list.

Since I'm replying to a question posted years ago, it is worth mentioning that modern C++ discourages the use of `new`, `delete` and native (or naked) pointers. The use of handlers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are favored instead, since they automatically release the memory they own (check [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) idiom).

In this particular case, `std::vector` would provide all such features: heap-allocated data, use of initializer-list (like `{1, 2, 3}`), handlers and move semantics among other features.

For stack-allocated arrays you can consider `std::array`, should you need them.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can define constant array, like myConstArray[] = {1, 2, 3} and do memcpy after new int[3].

Comment: more generally, use std::copy to copy objects rather than bit patterns.

Comment: Unfortunately this is inefficient at best, and impossible at worst (if the type is a class without copy/assignment).

Comment: With type which is a class without copy/assignment it would be impossible to use constant array at all.

Answer (score 3):

`{1,2,3}` is a very limited syntax, specific to POD structure initialization (apparently C-style array was considered one too). The only thing you can do is like `int x[] = {1,2,3};` or `int x[3] = {1,2,3};`, but you can't do neither `int x[3]; x={1,2,3};` nor use `{1,2,3}` in any other place.

If you are doing C++, it is preferable to use something like std::vector instead of C-style arrays, as they are considered dangerous - for example you can't know their size and must delete them with a `delete[]`, not a normal `delete`. With std::vector you will still have the same initialization problem, though. If I used such initialization a lot, I would most probably create a macro assigning to a dummy local variable and then copying memory to the destination.

EDIT: You could also do it like this (std::vector still preferable):

```
int* NewArray(int v1, int v2, int v3) { /* allocate and initialize */ }
int* p = NewArray(1,2,3);
```

but then you'll have to override the function with different number of arguments, or use va_arg which is, again, unsafe.

EDIT2: My answer is only valid for C++03, as other people mentioned C++0x has some improvements to this.

Answer (score 0):

C++0x standard has the special type called `initializer_list` and the special syntax for it (type of expression `{1, 2, 3}` is `std::initializer_list<int>`). `std::vector` and `std::array` have constructors from it, so you can write `vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3}`.

There is no good solution in C++98/C++03.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general answer that works for *all* types, then what you do is:

1. malloc() or operator new() to create an array of uninitialised storage of the right length, calculated by nelts * sizeof(T)
2. Make an array consisting of the argument for a constructor for each element.
3. Apply the constructor in placement form to each element using the corresponding argument.

This only works if the same constructor will do for every element. If not, you will need a more complicated data structure and algorithm to choose the right constructor for each element.

A special case of this is to use an array of the actual elements and use the copy constructor, and a special case of that is when the type is a POD and you can just use memcpy to construct the lot at once.

If the constructor takes two arguments, you will need to write an initiator procedure (wrapper). For example:

```
pair<double> init_data[] = {make_pair(1.0,0.0), make_pair(3.0,4.0)};
void init(void *p, pair<double> d) { new (p) complex(d.first, d.second); }
```

and use that instead of just new(p).

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize it as follows:

```
int * myArray = new int[3];
*myarray=1;
*(myarray+1)=2;
*(myarray+2)=3;
```