# Can i push an array of int to a C++ vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there any problem with my code ?

```
std::vector<int[2]> weights;
int weight[2] = {1,2};
weights.push_back(weight);
```

It can't be compiled, please help to explain why:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int [2], std::allocator<int [2]> >::push_back(int*&)’
```

Comment: This would work with a vector of `std::array`s, `std::vector`s, or `std::pair`s. Your array is decaying to a pointer when it's passed in, which causes problems.

Comment: Thanks, chris. I understand that.

Comment: I think there's a good answer waiting to come out with all the specifics of why it doesn't work, which I would find an interesting and enlightening read. There's more to it than decaying, but I'm not sure what's all there.

Comment: Can this be made to work in C++11 using move semantics?  Or is that also doomed?

Comment: @templatetypedef, Even if it solves pushing it in, there's other issues like copying it. I'm not totally sure whether it would work for pushing or not, though.

Comment: @chris: Pointer-decay isn't a problem. Arrays just aren't copyable.

Comment: @GManNickG, Ah, I wouldn't have thought it would match after going through the function.

Comment: Is this a good answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4541707/1155650

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason arrays cannot be used in STL containers is because it requires the type to be copy constructible and assignable (also move constructible in c++11). For example, you cannot do the following with arrays:

```
int a[10];
int b[10];
a = b; // Will not work!
```

Because arrays do not satisfy the requirements, they cannot be used. However, if you *really* need to use an array (which probably is not the case), you can add it as a member of a class like so:

```
struct A { int weight[2];};
std::vector<A> v;
```

However, it probably would be better if you used an `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 5):

You cant do that simply.

It's better you use either of these:

1. `vector <vector<int>>` (it's basically a two dimensional vector.It should work in your case)
2. `vector< string >` (string is an array of characters ,so you require a type cast later.It can be easily.).
3. you can declare an structure (say S) having array of `int`  type within it i.e.

   `struct S{int a[num]}` ,then declare vector of
   `vector< S>`

So indirectly, you are pushing array into a vector.

Comment: Why a string? The question is about pairs of `int`s.

Comment: Y u use string?  Y not vector?

Comment: No, vector of vector (of int).  Strings are for holding characters.  He wants to hold integers.

Comment: ya u can do that too..but strings can also be an option..Moreover,typecasting ain't a problem..

Comment: In bad-programmers-land... everything's possible!
One time I saw a generic container implementation where string's characters were stored as floats.

Answer (score 5):

Array can be added to container like this too.

```
    int arr[] = {16,2,77,29};
    std::vector<int> myvec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) );
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays aren't copy constructable so you can't store them in containers (`vector` in this case). You can store a nested `vector` or in C++11 a `std::array`.

Comment: Are the statements `std::vector<int[2]> weights;` and `std::vector<int*> weights;` equivalent?

Comment: No, they name different types and the array doesn't degrade to pointer at that point.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is:

```cpp
    std::vector<int*> weights;
    int* weight = new int[2];
    weight[0] =1; weight[1] =2;
    weights.push_back(weight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `std::array` instead of simple array:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> weights;
std::array<int, 2> weight = {1, 2};
weights.push_back(weight);
```

or with a constructor:

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> weights;
weights.push_back(std::array<int, 2> ({1, 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
vector<int*>  .That will definitely work.
```

A relevant discussion on the same topic : [Pushing an array into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541556/pushing-an-array-into-a-vector)

Comment: It'll compile.  I don't think it'll do what anybody would rationally want to do!  If the array is on the stack, your solution will crash.

Comment: Could you tell me Why not? I just tried a simple example,and it worked as expected. The vector just stores the starting address of the array.So, if you want to access the nth element, just look up on the vector,and go to the nth location.

Comment: @Arvind: Right.  And everything works until the array leaves scope, or you expect that making a copy of the `vector` makes a deep copy.  Then strange things start happening.

Comment: I misspoke.  If the array goes out of scope, you now have a pointer to random memory in your vector.

Comment: @Managu,@Steven -Yeah,I realized that as well. Should have mentioned that in the answer. If anyone is using raw pointers in stl containers,they better visualize memory layout first!! :-)

Comment: @MrROY Did this answer work for you? If so,you could upvote the same. Someone who comes in here and sees an answer with -1, might not even bother looking at the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Situation like:

```
int arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int[]> v;
v.push_back(arr);
```

doesn't work with error "cannot initialize array in vector with .."

This, could be worked well

```
int * arr = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int*> v;
v.push_back(arr);
```

Answer (score -2):

To instantiate the vector, you need to supply a type, but int[2] is not a type, it's a declaration.

Comment: `int[2]` is a type. It's an array of 2 integers. Arrays are types too, just not as strongly as in other languages.

Comment: If it was a type, wouldn't the declaration be `int[2] myvar;`?

Comment: @RogerDahl: You would think so, but no.  You can create templates that would accept `int[2]` as a type([example](http://ideone.com/1mzLP)), it's just the type doesn't happen to meet the requirements of `std::vector`.  So it can't be used there.