# how to put the array of pointers into a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Edit: I do not want to only copy the data of Array into a vector. Actually i need the vector to store the total Array as the element. The Problem is that when i put the name of array in the vector, it was wrong.  My question is different with the [How do you copy the contents of an array to a std::vector in C++ without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping)

```
struct SPoint
{
  float32_t    ftX;
  float32_t    ftY;
};
std::vector<SPoint*> vecSPoint;
SPoint* pointArray[3]; // assume that there are already three pointers in this Array
```

I want to put this Array in the vector. But it does not work:

```
vecSPoint.pushback(pointArray);
```

What is the Problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: You are trying to push an array of `SPoint*` as an element of a vector of `SPoint*` - that's like trying to put a cargo ship full of cars in a parking lot.

Comment: Do you want to push the C-style array into the vector?

Comment: @Bathsheba yes. Do you know how to make it.

Comment: See the accepted answer on the duplicate.

Comment: @MatteoItalia  But I want to put Array into vector

Comment: `vecSPoint.push_back(*pointArray);`

Comment: @rayallen: you cannot put an array of something into a vector of something, what you *can* do is to put *the array's elements* into the vector.

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov: nope, that pushes just the first element.

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov  this way seems to be wrong

Comment: @MatteoItalia  you mean that the vector can not store the element as Array?

Comment: @rayallen: exactly; an `std::vector<SPoint *>` can only store elements of type `SPoint *`, not *arrays* of them. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatteoItalia, yep, you're right, my bad = \

Comment: @MatteoItalia  I want to put the Array into the vector. How can I change the vector  `std::vector<SPoint *>`  to make the storing possible?

Comment: @juanchopanza  I saw the quesition that might be similar with mine. But i think mine is different. I have edited it to make it clear.

Comment: OK. Arrays cannot be stored in vectors. [There are other duplicates for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044304/can-i-push-an-array-of-int-to-a-c-vector).